# jQuery Loop not switching attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a jQuery each loop to loop through elements but it is not updating once a status has been changed.

```
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded btn-info social_selector" data-network="twitter" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
</span>
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded indigo social_selector" data-network="facebook" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</span>
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded btn-warning social_selector" data-network="instagram" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>
<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
</span>
```

The jQuery loop is as follows;

```
//Social Selector
    $(document).on('click','.social_selector',function(){

        if($(this).attr('data-active') == 1){
            $(this).addClass('btn-disabled');
            $(this).attr('data-active', 0);
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('btn-disabled');
            $(this).attr('data-active', 1);
        }

        var networks = "";
        $(".social_selector").each(function(index, element){
            if($(element).data('active') == "1"){
                networks += $(element ).data('network')+', ';
            }
        });
        $('#social_network_holder').val(networks);

    });
```

The data-active is changed on each click when the jQuery loop is then ran so I am not sure if it is because the Dom is being updated between the loops?

```js
//Social Selector
$(document).on('click', '.social_selector', function() {

  if ($(this).attr('data-active') == 1) {
    $(this).addClass('btn-disabled');
    $(this).attr('data-active', 0);
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('btn-disabled');
    $(this).attr('data-active', 1);
  }

  var networks = "";
  $(".social_selector").each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).data('active') == "1") {
      networks += $(element).data('network') + ', ';
    }
  });
  $('#social_network_holder').val(networks);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded btn-info social_selector" data-network="twitter" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </span>
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded indigo social_selector" data-network="facebook" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
    </span>
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded btn-warning social_selector" data-network="instagram" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    </span>
```

Comment: did you tried with `if($(element).data('active') == "1")`

Comment: Yep, still get the same result. When I print .data('active') I get the first one updated then everything after that doesn't change. Normally it happens with click actions however I would do $(document).on() but I cannot do $(document) for an each function?

Comment: Try, $(".social_selector").on("click", function(){ loop here });

Comment: In addition to `.data('active') == "1"`, are you certain you have an *`input`* with the id `social_network_holder` and not a *`div`* or other that would need `.html()` ? [Otherwise it works](http://jsfiddle.net/unzjakt0/19/)  You dont show that part here ; )

Comment: Hi Ravneet, I have pasted the full code, this sites within a document on click.

Comment: so the problem is `networks` value remain same despite changing the `data-active` attribute value. Can you confirm if this is the issue?

Comment: Yes this is the problem

Comment: You still havent shown us the element with `id="social_network_holder"`

Comment: This is just an hidden input box with the id social_network_holder

Comment: Add it here, your code works fine, Im thinking there must be an issue with that input http://jsfiddle.net/unzjakt0/19/

Comment: what is the output of `console.log( networks );` on the console? put it just before setting it to the hidden input box

Comment: @gurvinder372 that bit works fine  http://jsfiddle.net/unzjakt0/19/ Im thinking it has to be his input, the one thing the OP wont show us, lol

Comment: the console log output is;

Click 1: facebook, instagram, linkedin, 
Click 2: facebook, instagram, linkedin, 
Click 3: facebook, instagram, linkedin, 
Click 4: facebook, instagram, linkedin, 

It should be 
Click 1: facebook, instagram, linkedin, 
Click 2: instagram, linkedin, 
Click 3: linkedin, 
Click 4: 

As I click through the elements

Comment: Could you kindly *show us your input* so we can at least rule that out?

Comment: The jsfiddle doesnt update the value in the textbox?

Comment: <input class="form-control" required="required" id="social_network_holder" name="social_networks" type="hidden">

Comment: updated the fiddle that updates the textbox http://jsfiddle.net/unzjakt0/20/

Comment: That works thanks @gurvinder372 it looks to be the .data() being replaced for .attr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `data()` method with `attr()` method

```
   $(".social_selector").each(function(index, element){
        if($(element).attr('data-active') == "1"){
            networks += $(element ).data('network')+', ';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the below which uses `.data('active')` instead of `.attr('data-active')` or you could change them all to `.attr('data-active')`, either way , just make sure they are all the same, you have one that is different:

```js
   $(document).on('click','.social_selector',function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        
        if($this.data('active') == 1){
            $this.addClass('btn-disabled');
            $this.data('active', 0);
        }else{
            $this.removeClass('btn-disabled');
            $this.data('active', 1);
        }

        var networks = "";
        $(".social_selector").each(function(index, element){
            if($(element).data('active') == 1){
                networks += $(element ).data('network')+', ';
            }
        });
        $('#social_network_holder').val(networks);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded btn-info social_selector" data-network="twitter" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>twitter
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
</span>
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded indigo social_selector" data-network="facebook" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>facebook
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</span>
<span class="btn btn-icon btn-rounded btn-warning social_selector" data-network="instagram" data-account-id="1" data-active='1'>instagram
<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
</span>
<input class="form-control" required="required" id="social_network_holder" name="social_networks" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5f02keap/2/) .

Just check if you require this

```
$(document).on('click','.social_selector',function(){

        if($(this).attr('data-active') == 1){
            $(this).addClass('btn-disabled');
            $(this).attr('data-active', 0);
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('btn-disabled');
            $(this).attr('data-active', 1);
        }

        var networks = "";
        $(".social_selector").each(function(index, element){
            if($(element).attr('data-active') == 1){
                networks += $(element ).attr('data-network')+', ';
            }
        });
        $('#social_network_holder').val(networks);
alert(networks)
    });
```

Comment: You should mention what you changed so the OP understands what was wrong ;)

Comment: @DelightedD0D  Yeah I was just in hurry ,,, even then you posted earlier than me mate :D